# How to persist certain redux store properties to disk?

Tags: reactjs, redux

In my `redux` app I have some settings that should be persisted to disk when they change (as JSON file) and loaded with the app (to fill the initial state of the store).

I guess app settings are state, so they belong in the store. Then I have actions that modify settings, either like `SETTINGS/CHANGE` with payload `{name:'settingName', value: 'settingvalue'}` or fine grained like `SETTINGS/UNITS` with payload `'metric'` or `'imperial'`.

Now I need something that intercepts certain state changes/action submissions and persist them to disk as serialized JSON. Is this something the `settings` reducer should do itself or better some kind of middleware that can perform this async in the background?

How would that look like in code?

Comment: There is the https://github.com/michaelcontento/redux-storage middleware you could take a look at, it does the same but for localStorage.

Comment: Looks exactly like I was looking for. Will give it a try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to write to localStorage in a Redux app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35305661/where-to-write-to-localstorage-in-a-redux-app)

Answer (score 1):

You may use `localStorage` API as krs said. Care because it only allows string values, so you may need to stringify your objects before storing them:

```
var config = {
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bar'
}

// Store:
localStorage.setItem('config', JSON.stringify(config));

// Get
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('config'));
```