# Can you, or should you use localStorage in Redux's initial state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, flux

For example...

```
export const user = (state = {
  id: localStorage.getItem('id'),
  name: localStorage.getItem('name'),
  loggedInAt: null
}, action) => {
    case types.LOGIN:
      localStorage.setItem('name', action.payload.user.name);
      localStorage.setItem('id', action.payload.user.id);
      return { ...state, ...action.payload.user }

    default:
      return {  ...state, loggedInAt: Date.now() }
}
```

That's a scaled down version of what I'm doing, default returns the state from localStorage as expected. However the state of my application is actually blank once I refresh the page.

Comment: what do you mean `should you?` ? depending on your application needs.

Comment: @AvraamMavridis if feels like a bad practice somehow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to write to localStorage in a Redux app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35305661/where-to-write-to-localstorage-in-a-redux-app)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Redux [`createStore`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/createStore.html) 2nd param is intended for store initialization:

```
createStore(reducer, [initialState], [enhancer])
```

So you can do something like this:

```
const initialState = {
  id: localStorage.getItem('id'),
  name: localStorage.getItem('name'),
  loggedInAt: null
};

const store = createStore(mainReducer, initialState);
```

Since reducers should be pure functions (i.e. no side effects) and `localStorage.setItem` is a side effect, you should avoid saving to localStorage in a reducer.

Instead you can:

```
store.subscribe(() => {
    const { id, name } = store.getState();

    localStorage.setItem('name', name);
    localStorage.setItem('id', id);
});
```

This will happen whenever the state changes, so it might affect performance.

Another option is to save the state only when the page is closed (refresh counts) using `onBeforeUnload`:

```
window.onbeforeunload = () => {
    const { id, name } = store.getState();

    localStorage.setItem('name', name);
    localStorage.setItem('id', id);
};
```

Comment: And yet another option is to use something like pouchDB and couchDB with middleware to help keep the store stateless.

Comment: what about writing to localstorage in the action creators? they are allowed to have side effects. also, is reading via `localstorage.getItem` to load initial state in the reducer parameter as OP describes a side effect?

Comment: You can use localStorage in action creators for granular state saves. Although I would still prefer a central save state that I can tune. Reducer should be pure functions, and adding data from localStorage in the body of the function is a side effect.