# Reactjs, what's the best option for save user data in browser?

Tags: javascript, authentication, browser, reactjs

I'm developing a front-end project using reactjs. I'm saving the return from my server using localStorage, is there a more efficient & secure method for saving user data in the browser?

```
localStorage.setItem('user', data);

// Recupere Data
var user = localStorage.getItem('user');
console.log(user);


/* Output */
{_id:1, name: "name here", email: "email@email.com" }
```

Comment: I think this question has nothing about React, you could search solutions for authentication persistent

Comment: Yes, i understand, i changed tags and add a tag authentication... I put Reatctjs because i'm developing using reactjs..

Answer (score 1):

yes use Redux with local storage: [Where to write to localStorage in a Redux app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35305661/where-to-write-to-localstorage-in-a-redux-app).

use memonization and service workers with caching capability. if your app is progressive