# how to set initial initialState's reducer from localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a shopping cart website and cart of user stored in `localStorage`.

now, I want to initial my store with my localStorage when my page will refresh but I get this error:

```
localStorage is not defined
```

cart.reducer.js:

```
import { cartConstants } from '../constants';
import { cartHelper } from '../helpers'

const initialState = []

function cart(state = initialState, action) {
  if(state.length == 0){
    state = cartHelper.getCart(); // error line
  }

  switch (action.type) {
    case cartConstants.CART:
      return action.cart

    default:
      return state
  }
}


export default cart
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [where-to-write-to-localstorage-in-a-redux-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35305661/where-to-write-to-localstorage-in-a-redux-app)

Comment: Are you running this code in browser? Or is this server side rendered application? Also can you share the code where you localStorage?