# React-Redux, LocalStorage: TypeScript error while saving data lcoally

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, local-storage

I am learning **React-Redux** and **TypeScript**. 
In my small app I want to use **localStorage** to save data locally.
I tried to solve it  according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35305661/where-to-write-to-localstorage-in-a-redux-app), but encountered a typescript error. I tried to define type  **any** as a temporary solution, but it didn't help.

```
Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

Since there are 2 **actions**, **reducers**, I had to use **combineReducers**. For side effects I am using **thunk middleware**.
I assume **store** is the correct component to save data. 
Any help is appreciated

rootReducer.ts

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import carReducer from './Car/CarReducer'
import ProductReducer from "./Products/ProductReducer"

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
     car: carReducer,
    products: ProductReducer
})

export default rootReducer
```

store.ts

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

import RootReducer from './RootReducer'

 const persistedState = localStorage.getItem('state') ?
 JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('state')) : {} // <--- typescript  error here 
 
const store = createStore(
  RootReducer,
  persistedState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
)

store.subscribe(()=>{
  localStorage.setItem('reduxState', JSON.stringify(store.getState())) 
}) 

export default store
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript doesn't have a way to know that calling `getItem` multiple times is going to result in the same thing being returned each time. So while you do check for null with the first value that's returned, this makes no difference to the second value.

The fix is to just call it once, and save the result to a variable:

```
const temp = localStorage.getItem('state');
const persistedState = temp ? JSON.parse(temp) : {};
```

Comment: @ Nicholas Tower thanks for answer. It solved  typescript problem. 
Is there anything missing in my code or should I add any functionality to save data locally. I checked , when I refresh the page, nothing is saved, but in application in devtools     I see  as a key "reduxState" and value one of the products added in basket.

Comment: In your code snippet, you're using `"reduxState"` when setting, but `"state"` when getting.  They'll need to be the same.

Comment: @ Nicholas Tower thank you so much. You saved me :)